# How can i make react-bootstrap form components work well with same-named formik components?

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-bootstrap, formik

First, I made a form validated with formik. After that, my team decided we would style with react-bootstrap. This library has a `<Form>` object, same as Formik. But it is not validating correctly. It either throws input fields as invalid all the time, thus putting its borders red, or as correct all the time.

I suspect it is a matter of combining libraries that work both with forms and have same-named components. I managed to make it work with original bootstrap library. But I still wanted to know why this happens and if it has some solution.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import '../FormStyles.css';
import * as yup from "yup";
import { Formik, Form, ErrorMessage, Field } from 'formik';

const TestimonialForm = ({ testimonial = null }) => {

     const initialValues = {
    name: testimonial?.name || "",
    description: testimonial?.description || "",
    image: testimonial?.image || ""
  };

 const schema = yup.object().shape({
      name: yup.string().min(4, "Name must be at least 4 characters long.").required("You have to provide a name."),
      description: yup.string().required("You have to provide a description."),
      image: yup.string()
      .matches(
        /\.(jpg|png)$/,
        "We only support .png or .jpg format files."
      )
      .required("You have to provide an image.")
    });

<Formik
        initialValues= {initialValues}
        validationSchema = {schema}
        >
```

Here's the form with Formik components

```
{({}) => (
            <div>
        <Form className="form-container">
            <Field 
            className="input-field" 
            type="text" 
            name="name" 
            placeholder="Testimonial title"/>
            <ErrorMessage name="name" />
            <Field 
            className="input-field" 
            type="file" 
            name="image" 
            placeholder="Testimonial image"/>
           <ErrorMessage name="image" />
            <button className="submit-btn" type="submit">Send</button>
        </Form>
           </div>
        )}
        </Formik>
```

Here's with react-bootstrap components (I only change the import values.) This are the ones that don't validate well.

```
{({touched, errors}) => (
            <div>
        <Form className="form-container" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <Form.Group controlId="name">
            <Form.Control
            className="input-field" 
            type="text" 
            name="name" 
            isInvalid={name.touched && errors.name}
            placeholder="Testimonial title"/>
                        <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
              {errors.name}
            </Form.Control.Feedback>
             </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group controlId="image">
            <Form.Control
            className="input-field" 
            type="file" 
            name="image" 
            isInvalid={image.touched && errors.image}
            />
                      <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
              {errors.image}
            </Form.Control.Feedback>
             </Form.Group>
            <button className="submit-btn" type="submit">Send</button>
            {message && <div>{message}</div>}
        </Form>
           </div>
        )}
        </Formik>
```

Comment: I believe you need to pass down Formik's handleSubmit property down to react-bootstrap's form.


I think Formik's Form component may be binding the onSubmit to your Form's submit handler automatically using context. But now that you are using a different component, you'll have to bind the form submit handler manually.

Comment: already did it. But it still doesn't fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

I initialize a bootstrap Form import like this:

```
import {Form as myForm} from react-bootstrap;
```

then you can use it like this:

```
<myForm.Control type='text' id='name'/>
```

In this way it doesn't override it with Formik's Form component.